MongoDump connection is being forcibily closed
Right now, I'm working with a M0 free tier cluster. The logical size as of now on the cluster is 84MB. I have a few collections.
I want to be able to back this database up and create a local backup on my hard disk so I can use it to restore my DB in case of any issues.  However the mongodump process is being interrupted.
Currently when I run this on my CLI
mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://UserName:Password.mongodb.net/" --gzip --archive="Path/to/backup/backup_zip.gz" --db=myDB
I can back most of the collections, except for the largest one. As of this time there are around 300k entries. After attempting to backup the entries, it fails after around 60% of the collection.
2024-06-03T00:00:00.000+0000    Failed: error writing data for collection `myDB.collection` to disk: error reading collection: connection(connection shard) incomplete read of message header: read tcp 192.168.0.00:00000->AtlasClusterIP:27017: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
I have tried to just backup this collection by itself but the same error is occurring
Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Maybe your internet connection is not stable. Did you try mongoexport?

I checked my internet, while it is stable, i have not yet tried mongo export. Reason is that even the half successful try took 6 minutes, I heard mongodump is faster than export. Hence why i am using it. I will try export and see if its possible. Edit: Also the fact that mongoexport needs a collection name, whereas mongodump does not. I would like to export all collections

Just to provide an update, I tried mongoexport, it worked but it took 11 minutes for the biggest collection. I expect the rest to add 1 minute to the total time. Is it normal to take 11 minutes to export around 66MB of data(one collection). Is there anything I can optimise

84MB is not much, should not take long. I assume you have a slow internet connection.

I would say that I dont really have slow Internet speed. I am on a wired connection and have more than 100Mbps. I would not expect this to take very long which is why Im suspecting that im doing somthing wrong
